# Aptana getting path of Windows python interpreter instead of linux

Tags: aptana, ubuntu-10.04, pythonpath

I was working on a project using windows in Aptana. I changed my OS and installed ubuntu on unpartitioned space. I again downloaded Aptana for ubuntu and run it. I specified same workspace that I was using during windows as my that project partition is still there.

The problem I am having is that I am unable to use Aptana intelligence so should I change some paths e.t.c. or is there a way to remove data from workspace(data that tells info to aptana) and recreate project so that it take new info. I tried to see that data but didn't see data that aptana use from workspace or project directory.

Please tell what should be done in this sitaution. thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the workspace and it works fine now. After doing so it asked for some paths for interpreter and I gave that and it works fine now.